# VueJS - jsonq utility - not able to fetch values of a sub-node

Tags: vue.js, jsonq

We are using jsonq utility in VueJS to iterate and extract value from JSON string. We are facing an issue in fetching the values from a sub-node that is an array.

JSON String

```
{ "name": "Sachin", "id": "CUS0002", "science": [{"value":"Kesavan"}, {"value":"Vinu"}, {"value":"SR"} ], "english": [{"value":"Kesavan2"}, {"value":"Vinu2"}, {"value":"SR2"} ]}
```

### Our need

Fetch all the values under "science" array

### Code that we tried

```
var jsonq = jsonQ(datajson);
var avalues = jsonq.find("science", "value");
```

Above code does not fetch anything.

If we try

```
var avalues = jsonq.find("value");
```

it fetches all 6 values as an array - from both "science" and "english". Can you please let us know how do we specify to "find" method that it should return all values only from "science" array ? Appreciate your help in addressing this.

Comment: You can place a breakpoint on the `jsonq.find` line and then step through to see why it does not find anything.

Comment: Thanks Ivo, if I don't get a solution, I will try that out.